# MySql spatial data query for finding near locations using haversine formula

Tags: mysql, geospatial, spatial, spatial-index, spatial-query

Newbie here have optimum knowledge in mysql, but stuck on spatial query.

I peeked into many spatial data related questions for finding near locations around given lat/lon , but ended up with no proper result because of my different spatial table format (please provide link if there is a question already. I dunno much about spatial data query).

I have a table where we stored lat/lon as **Point** data type of **Geometry** type.!(Sorry if I'm wrong here)

**desc** of my table is as follows:

```
+-----------+----------------+
| Field     |    Type        |
+-----------+----------------+
|  id       |        Int(10) |
| property  |       geometry |
+-----------+----------------+
```

when i queried for viewing property data using `select astext(property) from mytable` query, it will return list of

```
POINT(10.1234 50.12356)
```

as a result of latitude and longitude.

Now I have [**haversine**](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) formulae for calculating nearest locations using mysql.

In the given link writer **[Mr.Ollie](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/author/admin/)** queried directly on columns latitude and longitude but in my problem latitude and longitude are stored as POINT data-type.

For achieving nearest locations

- do i need to first extract points from table and apply query on that

(i tried `select X(property),Y(property) from mytable;` to get lat/long values.)

or

- is there any other ways to directly apply haversine formula on my
  table.?

i am using MySql server version **5.5**

Please suggest me how to do it. Thanks in advance for all.

Find separate thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263012/need-experts-help-to-solve-minor-change-in-spatial-data-query)

Comment: ..in the **desc** of your table, you have `property => geometry` .. but then in your query, you have `select X(cordinates) .. from property` .. already, that much doesn't make sense. In the least, it seems you should have `select X(property) .. from THE_UNSTATED_TABLE_NAME` ..no?

Comment: @elrobis yes you are right. that was my mistake. i apologies editing my question.

Comment: Previously you mentioned an error message--are you still getting an error?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the X/Y values correspond to LONG/LAT, and *not* LAT/LONG which is a common mistake. It might be helpful to think of your query as `SELECT X(property) as long, Y(property) as lat FROM mytable;` ..in other words, is it possible you're getting these values reversed?

Comment: @elrobis yeah, now i managed to get lat and lon separately using x(property) and y(property).

Comment: please look at my updated query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some studies ended with some descent Haversine query

```
     select id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(12.91841) ) * cos( radians( y(property) ) ) * 
    cos( radians( x(property)) - radians(77.58631) ) + sin( radians(12.91841) ) * 
sin( radians(y(property) ) ) ) ) AS distance from mytable having distance < 10 order by distance limit 10
```

;

And please take a look at stored **LAT** an **LON** the way lat/lon stored in mytable is reverse.

Answer (score 1):

To answer:

> is there any other ways to directly apply haversine formula on my
>   table.?

I have a direct answer in a solution I solved recently. I had an issue with CPU performance having to apply the formula to a great deal of data. I solved this by realizing the data never changed and redundantly applying the calculation at write time. GLength, LineStringFromWKB, LineString, and GeomFromText do what you desire:

```
CREATE TABLE `locations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `altitude` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `previd` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `prevdist` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  INDEX `idx_user` (`user`),
  INDEX `idx_device` (`device`),
  INDEX `location` (`location`),
  INDEX `idx_time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `locations` SET 
`time` = NOW(), `location`= GeomFromText('POINT(@LAT @LONG)'), `user`= @USER,
`device`= @DEVICE, `altitude`= @ALT,
previd=(SELECT id FROM `locations` AS lc WHERE
  lc.`user`= @USER AND
  lc.`device`= @DEVICE AND
  lc.time < NOW()
  ORDER BY lc.time DESC LIMIT 1),
prevdist=IFNULL(ROUND(GLength(LineStringFromWKB(LineString(GeomFromText('POINT(@LAT @LONG)'), (SELECT location FROM `locations` AS lc WHERE
  lc.`user`= @USER AND
  lc.`device`= @DEVICE AND
  lc.time < NOW() ORDER BY lc.time DESC LIMIT 1)
)))*110400), 0);
```

Comment: uh... lol. whatcha need THAT for?! Looks like some NSA cellphone triangulation for Pegasus2.0 XKeyscore PRISM RDS... lol... you need the users device, altitude, location... AND time? lol. sounds invasive.