# Need expert's help to solve minor change in spatial data query

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

i have the following query to access the nearest locations around the given lat-lon. 
I followed **Mr.Ollie's** blog [Nearest-location finder for MySQL](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/) to find nearest locations around given lat-long using haversine formula.

But due to lack of much knowledge in spatial data query i failed to execute it properly, so looking for an expert's advice to solve this.

Here is my query

```
  SELECT z.id,
       p.distance_unit
                * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                * COS(RADIANS(z.(x(property))))
                * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(z.(y(property))))
                + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                * SIN(RADIANS(z.(x(property)))))) AS distance_in_km
 FROM mytable AS z
 JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
       SELECT  12.00  AS latpoint,  77.00 AS longpoint,
               20.0 AS radius,      111.045 AS distance_unit
   ) AS p
 WHERE z.(x(property))
    BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
        AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
   AND z.(y(property)
    BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
        AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
 ORDER BY distance_in_km
 LIMIT 15;
```

when i run this query i'm getting error as

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(x(property))))                 * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(z.(y(geo' at line 1
```

i also tried `z.(GeomFromText(x.property)))`

this is my table **desc**

```
+-----------+----------------+
| Field     |    Type        |
+-----------+----------------+
|  id       |        Int(10) |
| property  |       geometry |
+-----------+----------------+

select x(property) from mytable; //gives me lat 
select y(property) from mytable; //gives me lan
```

Where am i going wrong?
is this the way to achieve this.?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are assuming that once you have selected `z.id` in the query, that this gives you you direct access to the `x(property)` and `y(property)`

(Aside - do those names really have parentheses in them?)

So to me it looks like you should replace things like

```
* COS(RADIANS(z.(x(property))))
```

with something like

```
* COS(RADIANS( select x(property) from mytable where id = z.id ))
```

However on further thinking about it, I think that your `mytable` doesn't have the required structure.  From looking at the link, I believe that your `mytable` should have a structure more like:

```
+-----------+----------------+
| Field     |    Type        |
+-----------+----------------+
|  id       |        Int(10) |
| latitude  |        Float   |
| longitude |        Float   |
+-----------+----------------+
```

So that you can do something like

```
* COS(RADIANS(z.latitude))
```

**NOTE**

The above was based on me not understanding that MySQL supports spatial data types (for which I have no idea how to use)

**Update**

I just did some googling to understand the spatial types and found this:

[How do you use MySQL spatial queries to find all records in X radius? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209093/how-do-you-use-mysql-spatial-queries-to-find-all-records-in-x-radius)

which suggests that you **can't** do what you want to do with spatial data types in mysql.  Which thus brings you back to using a non-optimal way of storing data in `mutable`

However in re-reading that link, the comments to the answer suggest that you may now be able to use spatial data types. (I told you I didn't have a clue here)  This would mean replacing the query code with things like `ST_Distance(g1,g2)`, which effectively means totally rewriting the example.

To put it another way

> The example you gave presumes that spatial data types and testing of
>   geometries do not exist in MySQL.  But now that they do exist, they
>   make this set of example code irrelevant, and that you are in for a
>   world of hurt if you try and combine the two forms of analysis.

**update 2**

There are three paths you can follow:

1. Deny that spatial data types exists in MySQL and use a table that has explicit columns for `lat` and `long`, and use the sample code as originally written on that blog.
2. Embrace the MySQL spatial data types (warts and all) and take a look at things like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231960/31326  that seem to do what you want directly with spatial data types, but as noted in that answer there are some caveats.
3. Use a spatial type to hold your data, and use a `pre-query` to extract `lat` and `long` before passing it into the original sample code.

Comment: Thank you, But for storing geodata like latitude and longitude geometry type is more preferred in MySQL right.?

Comment: @h.APP.y  I understand about the desire to use spatial data types, but see my update

Comment: i already went through such questions but din't get appropriate result. So what should i do now to solve this(suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

Finally i followed [this link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL) and ended with this.
query is not optimized yet but working great.

here is my query

```
select id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(12.91841) ) * cos( radians( y(property) ) ) * cos( radians( x(property)) - radians(77.58631) ) + sin( radians(12.91841) ) * sin( radians(y(property) ) ) ) ) AS distance from mytable having distance < 10 order by distance limit 10;
```